# Binary Tree/ Binary Search Tree

Tags: data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree

Can a Binary Tree / Binary Search Tree only have the parent and one of the left or right nodes?
Or is it **mandatory** to have both the left and right nodes?

Answer (score 0):

Binary implies two. Binary trees have two children *pointers*, not necessarily with references to anything. Parent references are not necessary - that is up to implementation.

If nodes were mandatory to have both children elements, then the tree would be infinite and leaves would not exist.

So, options for a node are

- leaf
- left/right child only
- both children

Of course, there are alternative ways to think about a "tree". For example, take the [binary heap array implementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Heap_implementation).

[image]

Comment: I'd argue that the defining attribute of binary trees is the logical structure and that the representation by pointers is an implementation detail. Consider a complete binary tree (such as a heap) stored as an array, or a tree formed solely through parent pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is *nothing* mandatory other than just one rule (i.e. the maximum number of children that any binary tree node can have is **two**).

**Technically:**

Even a `NULL` is considered as a tree node when we define `TreeNode *root = NULL`. 
Though, it has no practical significance, we do pass them as argument while calling *insert, delete and display* methods.

So, as a coder, assuming that a binary tree will always comprise of at least a parent node can prove **fatal** if the sanity of `root` is not checked before processing a binary tree.

Answer (score 0):

It is not mandatory, you can create other types of links if you want. Define *up* and *down* pointers like this.

For a node *x* define up pointer *u(x)* as:

- if *x* is the right child, then *u(x)* is the parent of *x*
- if *x* is left child or root, then *u(x)* is the lowest node on the right path of *x*

For a node *x* define down pointer *d(x)* as:

- if *x*'s left subtree does not exist, then *d(x) = x*
- if left subtree exists, then *d(x)* points to the rightmost node of *x*'s left subtree

This is so called ring representation of a tree.

Answer (score 0):

A binary search tree is also a binary tree with additional properties. Any Binary tree node can have either 0 or 1 or 2 child nodes. So to answer your question, its okay to have only left or right nodes